# Can I generate a simple POJO per table via jOOQ?

Tags: java, jooq, jooq-codegen

I can easily generate record classes (e.g. `UserRecord` with all the fields and getter/setter ...).

But I need a simple POJO or a record with only data fields of the table (so that I can easily serialize/deserialize the data when communicating with another layer).

Is that possible via jOOQ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. You need to add these inside `generate` tag in pom.xml:

```
<pojos>true</pojos>
<pojosAsJavaRecordClasses>true</pojosAsJavaRecordClasses>
```